# Auto update a list/section of key points beamer

Tags: beamer

Is there a way in Beamer to keep a dedicated portion of each slide for "key questions," or "key points" section that automatically accumulates questions or points?  Sort of like in the below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Slide 1                                | Key Points: |
| other content of the slide can go here |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
-----------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
| Slide 2                                | Key Points: |
| Key Point 1                            | Key Point 1 |
| other content of the slide can go here |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
-----------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------
| Slide 1                                | Key Points: |
| Key Point 2                            | Key Point 1 |
| other content of the slide can go here | Key Point 2 |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
|                                        |             |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? It's a parallel structure to sections.

[image]

Code of Version two. Now prints the current keypoint on reps. frame .

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamersize{ text margin left=100pt }
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{pgffor}
%
%
\gdef\mykey#1#2{
    \ifnum#1<\thestateone
    #2
    \else
        \ifnum#1=\thestateone 
        \color{red}#2
        \fi 
    \fi
}
\def\mytemp{}
%Read In 
\IfFileExists{somemore.ou}%
%then
    {\input{somemore.ou}}%
%else
    {\message{Rerun!}}%
%
% Some Helper Counter
\newcounter{stateone}
\setcounter{stateone}{0}
% WriteStreams
\newoutputstream{superstream}
\openoutputfile{somemore.ou}{superstream}
%
\makeatletter
% Helper macro end
\AtEndDocument{%
    \addtostream{superstream}{\@charrb}%write out protected "{" see source2e
    \closeoutputstream{superstream}
}
%Helper macro begin
\addtostream{superstream}{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\mytemp\@charlb}
\makeatother
%
%User-macro 
\newcommand{\mykeynotes}[1]{%
    #1 %
    \stepcounter{stateone}%
    \addtostream{superstream}{%write to stream
        \noexpand\mykey{\thestateone}{#1} \noexpand\par% or what ever
    }%
%
}%
%
% Appearance 
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\huge \mytemp}
%
\begin{document}
%
% the seven who are one
\foreach \name in {Father, Mother, Smith, Warrior, Maiden, Crone, Stranger}{
\frame{
\mykeynotes{\name}
}
}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow I had no idea this was answered till I came back by chance! Thanks!